# Linux kernel: get information of page cache distribution over NUMA nodes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, numa, procfs

When Linux kernel runs on NUMA, each NUMA node has partially separate memory management. [There is](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt) `echo '?' > /proc/sysrq-trigger` function "*Will dump current memory info to your console.*" of [SysRq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) (implemented as [`sysrq_handle_showmem`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/sysrq.c?v=4.8#L318) and [`show_mem`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/show_mem.c?v=4.8#L12)) to get basic memory statistics for every NUMA node to system console, dmesg and system kernel log.

As I understand, there is data printed on memory usage by kernel's disk cache ([page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)) for every NUMA node, probably from `active_file:%lu inactive_file:%lu` code of [`show_free_areas`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c?v=4.8#L4153). (The line cached from `free` tool output?)

I want to monitor disk cache usage over numa nodes for long amounts of time with frequent updates; and I want not to fill entire console and dmesg with outputs from SysRq-`m`. I plan to find how multi-process or multi-threaded programs (not bound to core or node with affinity) interacts with pagecache pages placed in other node memory.

Is this information (pagecache memory usage per NUMA node) published for program access without using sysrq, by reading and parsing some special files in `/proc` or in `/sys`? Or is it needed to write new kernel module for this?

`free` tool uses `/proc/meminfo` to print [**cache**  *Memory used by the page cache and slabs*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html)  for entire system; not for every NUMA node. I was unable find per-numa memory stats in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html man page of proc 5.

There is numastat: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/numastat.txt but it has no pagecache memory statistics; as I understand it says only about cross-numa page allocation counts, which can be useless when processes are often move between NUMA nodes.

Comment: Hmm, there was `K(node_page_state(pgdat, NR_ACTIVE_FILE)),` in [`show_free_areas`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_alloc.c?v=4.8#L4153), and same is used in drivers/base/node.c: `node_read_meminfo`. How to access it, when it was implemented? Is it documented in man pages; not only in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-devices-node ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `/sys/devices/system/node/nodeX/meminfo` files for every node with basic memory info, for example `/sys/devices/system/node/node0/meminfo` for NUMA node 0, `/sys/devices/system/node/node1/meminfo` for node 1, etc.

They should be similar to `/proc/meminfo` system-wide file format which is actually used by `free` utility; its man page has basic description of the `meminfo` format: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html

```
   free displays the total amount of free and used physical and swap
   memory in the system, as well as the buffers and caches used by the
   kernel. The information is gathered by parsing /proc/meminfo. The
   displayed columns are:

   total  Total installed memory (MemTotal and SwapTotal in /proc/meminfo)

   used   Used memory (calculated as total - free - buffers - cache)

   free   Unused memory (MemFree and SwapFree in /proc/meminfo)

   shared Memory used (mostly) by tmpfs (Shmem in /proc/meminfo)

   buffers
          Memory used by kernel buffers (Buffers in /proc/meminfo)

   cache  Memory used by the page cache and slabs (Cached and
          SReclaimable in /proc/meminfo)

   buff/cache
          Sum of buffers and cache
```

meminfo for NUMA is mentioned in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-devices-node

```
What:       /sys/devices/system/node/nodeX/meminfo
Date:       October 2002
Contact:    Linux Memory Management list <linux-mm@kvack.org>
Description:
        Provides information about the node's distribution and memory
        utilization. Similar to /proc/meminfo, see Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt
```

and full meminfo description is in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

You (I) need "Cached" line from numa node meminfo to get information about page cache distribution between NUMA nodes:

```
     Buffers: Relatively temporary storage for raw disk blocks
             shouldn't get tremendously large (20MB or so)
      Cached: in-memory cache for files read from the disk (the
             pagecache).  Doesn't include SwapCached
SReclaimable: Part of Slab, that might be reclaimed, such as caches
```

Some parts of used memory can be dirty:

```
    Dirty: Memory which is waiting to get written back to the disk
Writeback: Memory which is actively being written back to the disk
```

It also shows how much memory is used for userspace tasks as anonymous:

```
    AnonPages: Non-file backed pages mapped into userspace page tables
AnonHugePages: Non-file backed huge pages mapped into userspace page tables
```